# Install ipa file in iphone without adding it's device id into provision profile

Tags: iphone, objective-c

I have ipa files which are created with Adhoc provision profile. Now, i have one new device and i want to install all those ipa files in this new device. While doing so, i am getting error.
Can i install ipa files without adding new device id to provision profile ?
Or do i need to create those again with new provision profile containing new device id ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I know, Adhoc distribution lets your app running on maximum 100 devices. In order to manage that, developer must add those devices' UDID under his/her profile.

So, I don't think there's any possibility for your quest.

Cheers,
Thang

Comment: You're welcome iAsh. I have just got that information lately :)

Answer (score 1):

In your adhoc provisioning profile at the developer site add the new device id, download the provisioning profile on to the target and you are good to go.

Answer (score 0):

Nooo.... :p unfortunately not.

You have to add the device to the provisioning portal and then choose to include that device in the mobile provisioning certificate that you're including in the ipa file (you'll have to rebuild the project against the new provisioning profile). Unfortunately this is the only way to do it.